# ThinkScript close of the 15min Candle after the Previous Day High

Tags: thinkscript

My goal is ultimately to plot two levels from yesterday and fill them with a cloud color.

I can get the previous day's highest high like this:

```
 high(period = "day" )[1];
```

That will be the top level.  For the bottom level, I want to get the close of the 15min candle that follows it.

My difficulty is that I don't know how to tell ThinkScript how to reference that candle.

The levels I get need to be absolute price levels, so that changing the time scope of the chart doesn't change the plotted levels.  (For example, I do not want the close of the 1min candle after yesterday's high of day -- only that of the 15min candle.)

If I were writing it in pseudo code it might look something like this:

```
PriceLevel_1 = Yesterday(highest high during normal trading hours); #I've got this

PriceLevel_2 = The close of the 15min candle after PriceLevel_1;
```

Does anyone have a code snippet that can do this?  I've spent literally days searching online for an answer and trying unsuccessfully to code that second level.